# How to re-mount a docker volume without overriding existing files?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When running Docker, you can mount files and directories using the `--volume` option. E.g.:

```
docker run --volume /remote ./local myimage
```

I'm running a docker image that defines [VOLUMES](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume)s in the Dockerfile. I need to access a config file that happens to be inside one of the defined volumes. I'd like to have that file "synced" on the host so that I can edit it. I know I could run `docker exec ...`, but I hope to circumvent that overhead for only editing one file. I found out that the volumes created by the VOLUMES line are stored in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<HASH>/_data`.

Using `docker inspect` I was able to find the directory that is mounted:

```
docker inspect gitlab-runner | grep -B 1 '"Destination": "/etc/gitlab-runner"' | head -n 1 | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

Output:

> /var/lib/docker/volumes/9c233c085c36380c6c33035222c16e5d061368c5060cc81dda2a9a713a2b2b3b/_data

---

So the question is:

Is there a way to re-mount volumes defined in an image? OR to somehow get the directory easier than my oneliner above?

---

**EDIT** after comments by zeppelin I've tried rebinding the volume with no success:

```
$ mkdir etc

$ docker run -d --name test1 gitlab/gitlab-runner
$ docker run -d --name test2 -v ~/etc:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner

$ docker exec test1 ls /etc/gitlab-runner/
certs
config.toml

$ docker exec test2 ls /etc/gitlab-runner/
# empty. no files
$ ls etc
# also empty
```

`docker inspect` shows correctly that the volume is bound to `~/etc`, but the files inside the container at `/etc/gitlab-runner/` seem lost.

Comment: > Is there a way to re-mount volumes defined in an image?
You should normally be able to override the volume definitions (as specified in Dockerfile), with the --volume command line switch. Or I'm missing a point ?

Comment: > somehow get the directory easier than my oneliner above?
You can use the "Go template" syntax, to extract it, like this `docker inspect -f '{{range .Mounts}}{{if eq .Destination "/etc/gitlab-runner"}}{{.Source}}{{end}}{{end}}' gitlab-runner`, however it is not really shorter.

Comment: @zeppelin thanks for the proposal with overriding, but the problem is it seems to override whatever files were at that position inside the container.

Comment: Yep, but that's actually what I would normally call a "re-mount" (override the mount point to a different directory). Can you elaborate a bit on what you have in mind ?

Comment: The use case here is: I'm using an official image of gitlab-runner, but I'd like to have the config file (/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml) from inside the container on my host, so I can easier edit it (manually and through puppet). I cannot simply put the file there because it's also written by the program itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ docker run -d --name test1 gitlab/gitlab-runner
$ docker run -d --name test2 -v ~/etc:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner
```

You've got two different volume types there. One I call an anonymous volume (a very long uuid visible when you run `docker volume ls`). The second is a host volume or bind mount that maps a directory on the host directly into the container. So each container you spun up is looking at different places.

Anonymous volumes and named volumes (`docker run -d -v mydata:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner`) get initialized to the contents of the image at that directory location. This initialization only happens when the volume is empty and is mounted into a new container. Host volumes, as you've seen, only get the contents of the host filesystem, even if it's empty at that location.

With that background, the short answer to your question is no, you cannot mount a file inside the container back out to your host. But you can copy the file out with several methods, assuming you don't overlay the source of the file with a host volume mount. With a running container, there's the `docker cp` command. Personally, I like:

```
docker run --rm -v ~/etc:/target gitlab/gitlab-runner \
  cp -av /etc/gitlab-runner/. /target/.
```

If you have a named volume with data you want to copy in or out, you can use any image with the tools you need to do the copy:

```
docker run --rm -v mydata:/source -v ~/etc:/target busybox \
  cp -av /source/. /target/.
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer was very clear and helpful. Unfortunately the image I'm using has a script set as ENTRYPOINT so I cannot run `cp ...` as CMD.

Comment: You can override the entrypoint with `--entrypoint`. Something like `docker run --rm -v ~/etc:/target --entrypoint /usr/bin/env gitlab/gitlab-runner -- cp -av /etc/gitlab-runner/. /target/.` if my memory on env options serves me.

Comment: Tried this, but it looks like the volumes are mounted before the entry point is run. So basically I'd need to run the container once to copy the directory out of the container and afterwards start it again with the volume mounted

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do. There's no way from docker to change the volume mounts after the container starts, and no way to have both a host volume and not have a host volume in the same location in the same container. If you always need the file as it is inside the image, consider whether it should be inside the volume at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid modifying data inside a container from the host directly, much nicer is when you wrap your task into another container that you then start with "--volumes-from" option when possible in your case.

Comment: Why avoid modifying data inside a container from the host directly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your problem, anyway, as for the documentation you mention,

> The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name
>   and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or
>   other containers. [...] The docker run command initializes the newly
>   created volume with any data that exists at the specified location
>   within the base image.

So, following the [example Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume) , after having built the image

```
docker build -t mytest .
```

and having the container running

```
docker run -d -ti --name mytestcontainer mytest /bin/bash
```

you can access it from the container itself, e.g.

```
docker exec -ti mytestcontainer ls -l /myvol/greeting
docker exec -ti mytestcontainer cat /myvol/greeting
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I know how to access the container, but I'd prefer to edit mounted files rather than run `docker exec` every time.